# Getting Password

Tags: java

I have a program in Java that has two classes, the Main class and the `appGUI` class.

This is the Main class:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        appGUI gui = new appGUI();
        gui.setVisible(true);

        String password = ""; //The password entered...
        try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(password.getBytes());
        System.out.println(new BigInteger(1, md.digest()).toString(16));

        } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    }
```

And this is the appGUI class:

```
    import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
/*
 * Created by JFormDesigner on Wed Apr 03 19:24:35 BST 2013
 */



/**
 * @author Hrach Ghapantsyan
 */
public class appGUI extends JFrame {
    public appGUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void loginButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO add your code here
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        // JFormDesigner - Component initialization - DO NOT MODIFY  //GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
        // Generated using JFormDesigner Evaluation license - Hrach Ghapantsyan
        loginPasswordField = new JPasswordField();
        loginUsernameField = new JTextField();
        usernameLabel = new JLabel();
        passwordLabel = new JLabel();
        loginButton = new JButton();
        titleLabel = new JLabel();

        //======== this ========
        setTitle("Experimental X | Administrator Login");
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        contentPane.add(loginPasswordField);
        loginPasswordField.setBounds(80, 65, 100, loginPasswordField.getPreferredSize().height);
        contentPane.add(loginUsernameField);
        loginUsernameField.setBounds(80, 35, 100, loginUsernameField.getPreferredSize().height);

        //---- usernameLabel ----
        usernameLabel.setText("Username:");
        contentPane.add(usernameLabel);
        usernameLabel.setBounds(20, 40, 55, usernameLabel.getPreferredSize().height);

        //---- passwordLabel ----
        passwordLabel.setText("Password:");
        contentPane.add(passwordLabel);
        passwordLabel.setBounds(20, 70, 55, passwordLabel.getPreferredSize().height);

        //---- loginButton ----
        loginButton.setText("Login");
        loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                loginButtonActionPerformed(e);
            }
        });
        contentPane.add(loginButton);
        loginButton.setBounds(80, 95, 100, loginButton.getPreferredSize().height);

        //---- titleLabel ----
        titleLabel.setText("Experimental X | Administrator Login");
        contentPane.add(titleLabel);
        titleLabel.setBounds(45, 10, 190, titleLabel.getPreferredSize().height);

        { // compute preferred size
            Dimension preferredSize = new Dimension();
            for(int i = 0; i < contentPane.getComponentCount(); i++) {
                Rectangle bounds = contentPane.getComponent(i).getBounds();
                preferredSize.width = Math.max(bounds.x + bounds.width, ``preferredSize.width);
                preferredSize.height = Math.max(bounds.y + bounds.height, preferredSize.height);
            }
            Insets insets = contentPane.getInsets();
            preferredSize.width += insets.right;
            preferredSize.height += insets.bottom;
            contentPane.setMinimumSize(preferredSize);
            contentPane.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);
        }
        setSize(270, 170);
        setLocationRelativeTo(getOwner());
        // JFormDesigner - End of component initialization  //GEN-END:initComponents
    }

    // JFormDesigner - Variables declaration - DO NOT MODIFY  //GEN-BEGIN:variables
    // Generated using JFormDesigner Evaluation license - Hrach Ghapantsyan
    private JPasswordField loginPasswordField;
    private JTextField loginUsernameField;
    private JLabel usernameLabel;
    private JLabel passwordLabel;
    private JButton loginButton;
    private JLabel titleLabel;
    // JFormDesigner - End of variables declaration  //GEN-END:variables
}
```

When I run the Java code, the appGUI class is activated which causes a pop-up. A login box pops-up.  When the login box pops up, A user is required to enter his or her username and password.

What I wanted to happen is when the user clicks on login, it submits the password to the Main class and does something like this:

```
    String password = "the password that the user just inputed";
```

In the:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to call main() again and not another method?

Comment: Im sorry, I didnt understand.  What's the difference?

Comment: static void main() is the entry point of a java app, it should not have much code except initializing your app.

Comment: Ok, so what should i do now?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

when your making the password string, you need to add a var to it so you can later define that the string = said var. EX.

```
String password = new String("Somthing");
```

then

```
 appGUI gui = new appGUI();

 if(gui.actionPerformed(loginPasswordField2).equals(password){

 }
```

Add that to your main class then
add this to your actionlister

```
  String loginPasswordFeild2 = new String(loginPasswordFild2)
```

you have to define the password beforhand but it will still work.

Comment: `new String("Password you want");` -- what is it for? simply write `"Password you want"`.

Comment: This is to declare a string variable and set it to the password you want.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it will be:

1. Make your appGUI a inner class of 'Main' Class (Please give a better name, lets call it Test for now.)
2. Declare your password as instance variable in 'Test' Class
3. Create Instance of the [Inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)

   ```
   Test q1=new Test()  
   appGUI gui = q1.new appGUI();
   ```
4. In your loginButtonActionPerformed method

   ```
          private void loginButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              // TODO add your code here
             password=loginPasswordField.getText();
          }
   ```
5. This won't completely solve your problem. The call to the inner class could be made in a separate thread, so that you 'Test' class /main thread waits till your user completes submission, then you can do your post parsing with MessageDigest

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In your `Main` class create a `PRIVATE String` variable for password. You can simply take your existing `String password` and move it to the class itself.

Then create `PUBLIC SetPassword` method to assign a value to this string, also in `Main` class.

In your `appGUI` class in the method that performs an action once user clicked on "Login" button call this `GetPassword` method and pass it the password string from GUI.

I hope the above should provide enough hints without me writing the actual code for you.